Is it possible to display values from a PRBS7 shift register to three, 7-segment displays (no Arduino or microcontrollers)?
I have a CD4015 lsfr connected to a CD4030 XOR gate, which implements a PRBS7 sequence.  My goal is to display the current value of the 7-bit output using the output pins of A and B of the CD4015.  I haven't found helpful discussions of this circuit that did not include Arduino or microcontrollers.
I suspect that I would connect the "A" register of the CD4015 to a BCD to 7-segment decoder, which would connect to the 7-segment display. I would repeat the configuration but for the "B" register.
How do I synchronize the display of the 7-bit value across the two displays?  It seems like I would use register "A"'s Q4A going high to signal something in register "B".
I'd appreciate your suggestions or links.  Thank you for your time and interest!

What you are asking is certainly doable, but boils down to making your own decoder out of discretes which is extraordinarily tedious. Is there a reason you don't want to use a microcontroller?

Your comment explains why I was having trouble finding a solution... tedium!  I hoped to easily view the random numbers without adding a lot of silicon.  Generally, how would you accomplish this goal?  Thanks for your time and help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To clarify, you are asking to decode and display a 7-bit binary input on a three digit decimal-coded 7-segment display. Even if a single chip existed to do this (which to my knowledge it does not), it would take less time to wire up an Arduino to display the binary input on a computer terminal over USB than it would to breadboard the hypothetical chip. I believe many inexpensive logic analyzers have this functionality as well.

What is the value of a couple of pseudo-random bits? Does it matter  if the bits are permuted before being mapped to 3*7 segments? How/why does this matter?

Yes it is possible.
If you have the three output bits as three signals you can do anything with them. Feed to a single 7-segment decoder for a number 1..7 or feed each three bits to three 7-segment decoders to display them like "101" separately.
In fact you can take any amount of bits and connect them to any amount of 7-segment decoders and the current tate of all bits is decoded to display. There is no need to synchronize.
If the 7-segment decoder needs a clock signal, you can use the same clock that is used for clocking the shift register.
